# "main isolate paused in debugger" when play video in web with flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

video thumbnail shows well but not automatically playing. i got "Main isolate paused in debugger error every time" in google chrome with updated flutter version. i use video_player dependency for that if you have any solution please let me know

```
    class _VideoPlayerScreenState extends State<VideoPlayerScreen> {
      late VideoPlayerController _controller;
      late Future<void> _initializeVideoPlayerFuture;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
       
        // Create and store the VideoPlayerController. The VideoPlayerController
        // offers several different constructors to play videos from assets, files,
        // or the internet.
        _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(
            "https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4");
        // Initialize the controller and store the Future for later use.
        _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
        // Use the controller to loop the video.
        _controller.play();
        _controller.setLooping(true);
      }
    
      @override
      void dispose() {
        // Ensure disposing of the VideoPlayerController to free up resources.
        _controller.dispose();
        super.dispose();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return FutureBuilder(
          future: _initializeVideoPlayerFuture,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              // If the VideoPlayerController has finished initialization, use
              // the data it provides to limit the aspect ratio of the video.
              return AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                // Use the VideoPlayer widget to display the video.
                child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
              );
            } else {
              // If the VideoPlayerController is still initializing, show a
              // loading spinner.
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }
    }
```